# What is a good design of a custom communication protcol?

Tags: network-programming, protocols

I have to implement a communication protocol stack in C. There exists already an outlining design. The stack consist of 3 layers (connection-control, security, fragmentation). The functionality of these layers is not relevant here. The idea is, that each layer processes an incoming/outgoing telegram according to its responsibility and hands it to the next layer in the stack. I thinks that’s the usual idea of a stack.

My question is, what a good design is and how are the dependencies of the various items of each layer.

I have thought of two approaches:

1. A chain like implementation:
   For an incoming telegram, a process-in data function of the connection control item is called by a preceding item (not in the scope of this post). Then the connection control does something with the telegram and then calls the security items process-in data function, then the security item does something and forwards the telegram to the fragmentation item. The same idea applies for outgoing telegrams, in a reversed direction by calling process-out data functions.
2. A central control item implementation: 
   In this approach a central control gets the an incoming telegram, it then calls the process-in data function of the connection-control which returns the telegram after doing something. Then the central control item calls the process-in data function of the security item and so on. 
   Maybe this central control item could be implemented as a state-machine, where each state represents one of the communication protocol layers mentioned above.

Comment: Is this an exercise? Otherwise, I would strongly recommend to consider existing protocols (and implementations) like the tcp/ip-protocol-suite, perhaps with extensions like ipsec, ssl or the like.

Comment: Why is it tagged in C though ? Also, maybe this question is more appropriate for [network engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) ?

Comment: @Ctx Tanks for the recommendation. However I have to provide the implementation of the already existing desing.

Comment: @VishaalShankar The implementation has to be in C, I've eddited my post.

Comment: @david The c tag is still barely relevant for your question, since you do not refer to anything language specific

Comment: @Ctx Oh, I understand now. I just thought to add this information about the language to avoid getting some spectacular object-oriented design patterns.